Symfony + doctrine: Can only configure "xml", "yml", "php", "staticphp" or "attribute" through the DoctrineBundle
upgrading symfony from 6 to 7 getting this doctrine error
In AbstractDoctrineExtension.php line 229:
                                                                                                                                                                     
  Can only configure "xml", "yml", "php", "staticphp" or "attribute" through the DoctrineBundle. Use your own bundle to configure other metadata drivers. You can r  
  egister them by adding a new driver to the "doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver" service definition.            

here is my doctrine.yaml file:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version:    '%env(DATABASE_VERSION)%'
        dbname:            '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
        host:              '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
        port:              '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
        user:              '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
        password:          '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
        driver:            '%env(DATABASE_DRIVER)%'
        charset:            UTF8
        options:
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY: '%DATABASE_PUB_KEY%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: '%DATABASE_PRIV_KEY%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%DATABASE_CA_CERT%'
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: false

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                rand: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Rand


The mapping type annotation in the orm configuration has been deprecated in version 6.4. You probably should move to attributes. Rector can help you with that.

It's type: attribute in doctrine.yml
